# Instagram Basic Display API connection error

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to build a simple application to get a users latest instagram posts. I have followed all of Facebooks ['Get Started'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started/) guide, and am using the following URL to connect to the Instagram Authorization window:
"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={MY CLIENT ID INSERTED HERE}&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/handleAuth&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code"

No matter what I do, the only response I can get from Instagram is:

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out using the url for the Authorization Window as the form action url does't work for some reason. I've switched to a function that uses window.location.href = (authorization window URL), which is now working.